# Deciphering coord. ref. in R – very basic question

Tags: coordinate-system, r

I'm trying to make sense of the `coord. ref.` parameters for rasters in R. For example, for a given raster, `crs()` gives the following:

```
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

The `datum` and `ellps` parameters make sense, but the `proj` argument has me confused. Does this mean that the raster is unprojected as opposed to something like `+proj=utm +zone=36` which would refer to projected data? Also, what is the meaning of `+no_defs`? Unfortunately, I have been unable to find documentation that explains the string output by `crs()`.

Comment: It is not only for R, they are the [ProJ.4](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/wiki) parameters, universal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+no_defs` - Don't use the defaults from the defaults file.

`+proj=longlat` - This refers to a geodetic/geographic CRS. This means the longitude is the X axis and latitude is the Y axis.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Mintx. To clarify then: this means that the raster is unprojected, as it's a geodetic/geographic CRS?

Comment: This gets into technicalities, but I think the term "unprojected" is a bit of a misnomer. As soon as you visualize geographic CRS data in 2D, there is a mathematical projection at work.  (usually it's viewed in an equirectangular projection)